# What's the difference between .loc[index, col] and .loc[index][col]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this, with a "dense" first column and a "sparse" second column:

```py
# python 3.7.1, pandas 0.23.4.

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(1,5), 'col2': [5, '', 7, '']})

missing_values_index = df[df['col2'] == ''].index
```

---

I tried two methods to assign **col1** values to **col2** missing values.

**Method 1 (does not work, df remains unchanged):**

```py
df.loc[missing_values_index]['col2'] = df.loc[missing_values_index]['col1']
```

---

**Method 2 (works ok):**

```py
df.loc[missing_values_index, 'col2'] = df.loc[missing_values_index, 'col1']
```

---

I thought these were just two ways of writing the same thing. Can someone explain what is really happening here?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087) explains the difference and its consequences in gory detail.

Comment: Also, read the docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=chained#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) on chained assignments.

Comment: when you print it show the same , when you assign it , it is not

Comment: Hi, did my answer solved your problem? if so, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The second method you mentioned "works ok", so let's talk about why the first method doesn't work!

I think the *core* of the problem is when we try to assign a value to a **copy of an object**, instead of the object itself. I can rewrite your first method like this:

```
something = df.loc[missing_values_index]
something['col2'] = df.loc[missing_values_index]['col1']
```

Now here is when the problem manifests itself. According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=chained#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing), it **isn't** known that the first line creates a `view` or a `copy`. That's why it throws a `SettingWithCopy` warning and prevents you from assigning; Because if Pandas can't be sure that your assignment works, it can't let you do it!